# What is, if any, the mid() function equivalent for a 1 dimension range/array, instead of a string?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, offset, google-sheets-query

What is, if any, the mid() function equivalent for a 1 dimension range/array, instead of a string? Say, I need to get the 5th to 8th row of a 10 row range, how would you do it?

Comment: Range/Array are two totally different things, do you want a solution that can do both or are you just wanting to know how to do it with a Range?

Comment: Oh? I always though they're kinda the same thing. Could you explain the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get the 5th to 8th row of a 10 row range

The easiest way to do it is with Query

```
=query(A1:A10,"limit "&8-5&" offset "&5,0)
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks! Could you explain the syntax tho, query() is one tough function to learn.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage just do ctrl+f limit or offset to read about it

Answer (score 0):

or try:

```
=OFFSET(A1:A10, 4, 0, 4)
```

[image: 0]

`4, 0, 4` stands for: remove first 4 rows, stay in the same column, bring up 4 rows

Comment: I was thinking of doing this one as well but because he said `range/array` I realized it wouldn't work with a non-range `array`. But this is definitely the best way to do it if you are only working with ranges directly.